# Time Picker not working on bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

I have following code and it's not working as expected. When I click on timer icon, nothing happens.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu customScroll" role="menu" aria-labelledby="btn-append-to-body" ng-show="!myVm.showETA">
    <li role="menuitem">
        <a href="#">Start Time
            <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker">
                <input type="text" id="timepicker1" class="form-control input-small" placeholder="" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2"
                ng-model=myVm.startTime"
                ng-change="myVm.getETACount('startTime');myVm.applyFilterForResultCount()"
                />
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li role="menuitem">
        <a href="#">End Time
            <div class="input-group bootstrap-timepicker timepicker">
                <input type="text" id="timepicker2" class="form-control input-small" placeholder="" aria-describedby="sizing-addon2"
                ng-model="myVm.endTime"
                ng-change="myVm.getETACount('endTime');myVm.applyFilterForResultCount()"
                />
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <!--Clear div-->
    <li role="menuitem" ng-click="myVm.clearTimePicker()">
        <a href="#">
            <p>
                <span style="color:#40A8E2;">Clear</span>
                <span style="color:#333333;">  – ETA</span>
            </p>
        </a>
    </li>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#timepicker1').timepicker();
        $('#timepicker2').timepicker();
    </script>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you post jsfiddle?

Comment: its huge. this is small component in it

Comment: Ok. I think you are using Angularjs. So instead of using jQuery code directly, you should use Angular's Directives to work with jQuery plugin. Here you may find reference https://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/an-approach-to-use-jquery-plugins-with-angularjs/

Comment: Thanks Kalpesh Patel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to use the regular bootstrap.js file with angular unless you know how to write directives.  When using angular if you need to do some DOM manipulation or extend the markup or behaviors (event handlers) for element you should use directives.  For the timepicker you can just use the ui-bootstrap angular module https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/timepicker you will need to include the regular bootstrap.css and ui-bootrap-tpls.js then include the ui-bootstrap module dependency and you can use the directive.